# Comment time is same as the post time

Tags: date-time, date, comments

Here is my comments.php: http://pastebin.com/E5bz4aaW

The problem is that the threaded comment (the reply) showing my post date instead if the comment date. I checked in the database and it looks fine there. The date is the same but the time is good(11:13)

Example: http://cl.ly/0W2P1b0c2N0W151v1E1d/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-16%20at%2012.49.33%20PM.png

In my comments.php i can't find my threaded comment syntax, its probably in the comment_text() function, right? How can i edit that to make this problem disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the wp_list_comments function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments

It allows you to control the aspect of every comment, also the replies. Then, you define a callback function, which will be called when Wordpress creates each comment.

Your callback needs to start like this:

```
function commnents_callback($comment, $args, $depth) {
  $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;   
  global $post;

  // your HTML + PHP comment creation code here
}
```

Then, you can create the comments by using this code:

```
<?php if( $comments ): ?>
<ul>
<?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=commnents_callback'); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Using this, you can control the creation of every comment.

Comment: Tried that, i copied the callback from twentyten and its the same, the date is wrong:(